# Node JS Symmetric key encryption

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptojs, symmetric-key

I am using AES 256 to save the data in DB after encryption. 
Is there a way by which I can secure the encryption key from other junior developers?

Comment: If they should be able to encrypt or decrypt, no you can't.

Comment: Hi @Sirko
I'm using mongoose and by applying pre/post EVENT_TYPE hooks I'll be encrypting and decrypting the code. Means they will be working on the same project but on different layer.